# Проблема с Jquery WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Если я залогиненый открываю мобильную версию сайта и нажимаю на меню , то всё работает и в консоли нет ошибок. Но только я розлогиниваюсь , делаю тоже самое меню не открывается и в консоле появляются ошибки . Вот видео я записал ошибки https://www.screencast.com/t/felEpf4a

Как это исправить, подскажите?

Comment: Скорее всего в Вашей теме для не залогиненых пользователей удаляется jQuery migrate, возможно также что дерегистрится jQuery который подключается WordPress-ом и в теме подключается другая версия.

Comment: Тогда мне нужно найти решение как сделать так чтобы, jQuery migrate не удалялся для незалогиненых пользователей?

Comment: Если от этого никак не пострадает остальной функционал сайта. Я же так понимаю что это сторонняя тема, скорее всего это было сделано по каким-то определенным причинам. Можете поискать, jQuery migrate обычно удаляется на хук `wp_default_scripts`.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить плагин Enable jQuery Migrate Helper https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/. Тема устарела, её надо править, по-хорошему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему создавал плагин WP-Rocket, плагин оптимизации и кеширования, в нем стояла галочка Remove jQuery migrate.